# How to reverse GetHashCode

Tags: c#, hash

we used to learn `GetHashCode` in .NET works like this:

```
 public int GetStringHashCode( string value)
    {
        int hash1 = (5381 << 16) + 5381;
        int hash2 = hash1;

        int len = value.Length;
        int intval;
        int c0, c1;
        int i = 0;
        while (len > 0)
        {
            c0 = (int)value[i];
            c1 = (int)value[i + 1];
            intval = c0 | (c1 << 16);
            hash1 = ((hash1 << 5) + hash1 + (hash1 >> 27)) ^ intval;
            if (len <= 2)
            {
                break;
            }
            i += 2;
            c0 = (int)value[i];
            c1 = len > 3 ? (int)value[i + 1] : 0;
            intval = c0 | (c1 << 16);
            hash2 = ((hash2 << 5) + hash2 + (hash2 >> 27)) ^ intval;
            len -= 4;
            i += 2;
        }

        return hash1 + (hash2 * 1566083941);
    }
```

Now, how can i reverse this method? (i mean that how get a int value and return a string value(original string))

Comment: The fact int is 4 bytes while string can have any length already should give you a clue that you cannot  reconstruct string back from int...

Answer (score 5):

There is no real way to do it, you could try to work it backwards but it is going to give you an unintelligible mess, you will not get the "original string" back.

You loose information during the hashing process and there is no way to get that information back from the result.

Comment: Before you go downvoting me, the .NET `GetHashCode()` is not a cryptoghraphic hash, you can reverse the calculation because it does not rely on things that are not easily calculable in reverse (for example finding prime factors). You will need to make "guesses" on lost information, but there is nothing that is "slow" to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) for storing original strings and fast them extraction depending on hash.